# Erro de condição em vetor de string em C

Tags: c, array, string, condição, printf

Estou tendo dificuldade com um exercício em especifico:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    char nome[0][50], hoje[0][50];

    printf("Digite o nome do local: ");

    scanf("%s", &nome[0]);

    printf("Digite o dia: ");

    scanf("%s", &hoje[0]);
    toupper((char)hoje);

    if((hoje[0] == "SEGUNDA") && (strlen(nome) < 100)){
        printf("Nome é: %s\n", nome[0]);
        printf("Hoje é: SEGUNDA\n");
    }else if((hoje[0] == "TERÇA") && (strlen(nome) < 100)){
        printf("Nome é: %s\n", nome[0]);
        printf("Hoje é: TERÇA\n");
    }else{
        printf("Dia da semana nao é SEGUNDA e nem TERÇA");
    }

    system("pause >> null");
    return 0;
}
```

quando compilado, ele não considera o if e pausa o programa após os inputs e invertendo a condição `if(!(hoje[0] == "SEGUNDA") && (strlen(nome) < 100))` com o `!` ele printa, porem sai por ex: `Seu nome é: SEGUNDA, Hoje é: SEGUNDA` ele substitui a variável nome por hoje quando printa a output, o que pode ser ? o endereço ou alocação ? Obrigado.

Comment: É uma pena estar como duplicata, porque existe mais erros para alem dos citados. Como por exemplo converter uma string para maiscula e declaração da matriz mal feita.

Comment: Eu poderia usar a conversão de string para maiúscula como toupper((char)hoje[0]);  no caso ? Não entendi o por que o output esta parando antes também. Sou novato em C

Comment: Exato, um dos erros vai ser exatamente esse, esta pergunta não deveria de ter sido fechada. Vou tentar colocar um codigo para resolver isso. `int i=0; while (hoje[0][i]!='\0') {
    hoje[0][i] = toupper((unsigned char) hoje[0][i]);
    i++;
  }` a função `toupper` apenas converte UM caracter e nao a string, entao terá de percorrer cada caracter na string e converter para maisculo

Comment: Obrigado a boa vontade de me ajudar Fabio ! Entendi o lance do loop pra transformar em maiúsculo automático, será que vai assim antes de entrar na condicional ? for(int i =0;  i< strlen(&hoje[0]); i++){
  toupper((char)hoje[0][i]);
 }

Comment: O professor da faculdade colocou os exercícios com erros, pra que nós corrigírmos e identificar eles, porém acho que esse esta um pouco mais complicado do que esperava.

Comment: Sim, tambem pode, mas apenas `strlen(hoje[0])` sem o `&`. O resto dos codigos pode ler nos links que foi colocado aqui. Devia de fazer comparaçao de strings com o `strcmp()`

Comment: Ahh certo, bom ta acusando isso aqui [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strlen' from incompatible pointer type, e isso aqui no for  [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode, estou usando o Dev - C ++ de compiler, que nao é muito bom tambem mas é o que ele usa  =/

Comment: `strlen(nome)` é o endereço da matriz. `strlen(nome[0])` é o correto, terá de arranjar o codigo, porque o resto das coisas sao simples